# Testing User Authentication with Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Good day,

I am testing user authentication with Zend but now that I am logged in, then I log out again it is keeping me logged in, so I can't test to make sure it is working correctly.

I use:

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
if ($auth->hasIdentity())
```

It is always getting me as having an identity and allowing me to view the resource.

Is it possible to clear the cache, session or cookies on the logout, or a way to go about testing thoroughly without uncommenting the lines etc.

Thanks

Logout:

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        if ($auth->hasIdentity())
            $auth->clearIdentity();

        $this->_redirect('/');
```

Comment: Show the code of logout plz.

Comment: `$auth->clearIdentity();` is enough .But just for testing include this also `Zend_Session::destroy();` and test again.

Comment: @StevieG many times `clearIdentity()` not clear the full session so need to use the destroy function. If it will also not work then use the `session_destroy();` also.

Comment: There must be something else at play, maybe cookie authentication or cache as `Zend_Session::destroy();` and `session_destroy();` don't work as it still acts as though I'm logged

Answer (score 0):

I think,     $auth->clearIdentity(); is enough But For the Sake of testing Make your logout Action Like This,

```
 public function logoutAction() {
    Zend_Auth::getInstance()->clearIdentity();
    $storage = new Zend_Auth_Storage_Session();
    $storage->clear();
    $this->_helper->redirector('Action', 'Controller'); // back to main page
}
```